# Find rows where association count is between passed values

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to find all the rows with their count of associated model.

It should only return those rows which have count of associations between two passed values.

This is what I tried, but getting sql exception.

```
db.Employee.findAll({
    where: {
      $assignedJobCount$: {
        [Op.between]: [0, 100],
      },
    },
    include: [
      {
        model: db.AssignedJob,
        required: true,
        attributes: ['emp_id'],
      },
    ],
    attributes: [
      'id',
      'alternate_mobile',
      ['employee_unique_id', 'unique_id'],
      [Sequelize.fn('COUNT', Sequelize.col('AssignedJobs.emp_id')), 'assignedJobCount'],
    ],
    order: [['id', 'ASC']],
    subQuery: false,
    group: ['Employee.id'],
    limit: 20,
  });
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(mechanics));
};
```

It throws below error,

```
sql: 
'SELECT
    `Employee`.`id`,
    `Employee`.`alternate_mobile`,
    `Employee`.`employee_unique_id` AS `unique_id`,
    COUNT(`AssignedJobs`.`emp_id`) AS `assignedJobCount`,
    `AssignedJobs`.`id` AS `AssignedJobs.id`,
    `AssignedJobs`.`emp_id` AS `AssignedJobs.emp_id`
FROM
    `employee` AS `Employee`
INNER JOIN `assigned_jobs` AS `AssignedJobs` ON
    `Employee`.`id` = `AssignedJobs`.`emp_id`
WHERE
    `assignedJobCount` BETWEEN 0 AND 100
GROUP BY
    `Employee`.`id`
ORDER BY
    `Employee`.`id` ASC
LIMIT 20;',
  parameters: undefined
}
SequelizeDatabaseError: Unknown column 'assignedJobCount' in 'where clause'
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by converting `where` clause into `having` clause as below.

```
db.Employee.findAll({
    having: {
      assignedJobCount: {
        [Op.between]: [0, 100],
      },
    },
    include: [
      {
        model: db.AssignedJob,
        required: true,
        attributes: ['emp_id'],
      },
    ],
    attributes: [
      'id',
      'alternate_mobile',
      ['employee_unique_id', 'unique_id'],
      [Sequelize.fn('COUNT', Sequelize.col('AssignedJobs.emp_id')), 'assignedJobCount'],
    ],
    order: [['id', 'ASC']],
    subQuery: false,
    group: ['Employee.id'],
    limit: 20,
  });
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(mechanics));
};
```